# How much downtime does Rackspace Cloud have?

Tags: cloud-hosting, rackspace-cloud

I'm doing my due diligence in developing a plan to migrate to a cloud based server provider. We will need a small scale group of hosts. Rackspace Cloud Servers seem to provide exactly what we need. I've also investigated Amazon, Voxel, Linode and some others. I have a friend who has shown me emails from Rackspace about server outages due to failing hardware. The email describes downtime of up to 3 hours to migrate the host. What's more, the host is powered down during the maintenance.

Has anyone else experienced this with Rackspace Cloud? If so, how long were the outages?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say if 3 hours of downtime is an issue, then small scale hosting is not what you need.

You need to weigh the pro's and cons of clour vs dedicated, and inevitably is going to come down which is going to cost you more, the properly designed and managed hosting solution, or the downtime with no recourse as "cloud" providers do not offer the same 100% uptime as with their dedicated solution.